# Not sure why this isn't working - Javascript basic increment function

Tags: javascript

I am writing code to increment the most basic progress bar ever...... it just isn't working.
These are the variable used:

```
map.progress_bar = // the progress div that grows inside a container div that is the width of the screen (100%);

progress = 0;

state.window_width = // the width of the window or otherwise $(window).width();

setTimeout(function incProgress(){
        if ( map.progress_bar.width() < state.window_width ) {
            progress += 10;
            map.progress_bar.css({
                width: String(progress + '%')
            });
            console.log('progress: ', map.progress_bar.width());
            console.log('window: ', state.window_width);
            setTimeout(incProgress(), 300);
        }
    }, 300);
```

Please do not ask me to do setInterval. Please explain to me why on earth this does not work, I feel very unhappy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout(incProgress(), 300);`

You are **calling** the function and passing its *return value* (`undefined`) to `setTimeout`.

You need to pass a *function* to `setTimeout`.

Remove the `()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! its always a small mistake like that gets me in trouble :D